# Can't install Oracle's virtual box gpg key to apt on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apt

Here's what I tried.

1. Added their apt line, with distro "jammy", to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.
2. Downloaded their key from their [download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

At this point, I tried several approaches, none of them seemed to work. What I tried:

- `apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc`. I get a deprecation warning and an "OK" message. Key appears when I run "apt-key list". `apt update` reports missing key with same signature.
- (Removing the key from `apt-key`), creating a keyring file with `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:./oracle_vbox.gpg --import oracle_vbox_2016.asc`, copying that file to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`. `apt-key list` shows the key. `apt update` doesn't recognize it.

Here are the relevant outputs:

```
$ apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
...

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oracle_vbox.gpg
--------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid           [ unknown] Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]

$ sudo apt update
...
Get:8 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease [4,428 B]           
Err:8 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
...
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assure that the source.list is OK (should be as you state, but one never knows):

File: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox-jammy.list`

```
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib
```

Add the key that you've downloaded from [oracle/virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc) and see if it's present:

```sh
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --import oracle_vbox_2016.asc
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --list-sigs


  [...]
  pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
        B9F8D658297AF3EFC18D5CDFA2F683C52980AECF
  uid           [ unknown] Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
  sig 3        A2F683C52980AECF 2016-04-22  Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
  sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
  sig          A2F683C52980AECF 2016-04-22  Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
```

Update the apt repository lists:

```sh
sudo apt update

  [...]
  N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

This "Notice" message is OK, they deliver x86-64-bit releases only.

See if Oracle's VirtualBox is offered for installation:

```sh
apt search virtualbox

  [...]
  p   virtualbox-7.0                                                              - Oracle VM VirtualBox                                                                 
  [...]


apt show virtualbox-7.0

  Package: virtualbox-7.0
  [...]
  APT-Sources: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy/contrib amd64 Packages
  Description: Oracle VM VirtualBox
  [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it's embarrassing.

The apt line suggested to add was:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib
```

I missed that it set a specific signing key, with explicit path. That eliminates the use of the generic gpg keyring, causing my adding of the key to the keyring to not take effect.

Comment: can you tell how you solved it?
can i just change the sigend-by= path to someting *general* or what is the best way?

Comment: Either place the key where the path points or remove the "signed-by" part from the deb line and add their key to the general authorized keys.